# Permanently down/disable network interface in opensuse

Tags: wireless-networking, opensuse, network-interface

I have two wireless cards in my computer. One bad one that cant be removed and one good one the I actually want use. Opensuses network manage automatically loads both and switches between the other which causes my internet connection to go out. I can temporarily disable the bad one with ifconfig wlan0 down, but this does not hold when I restart the computer. Wlan0 will pop back up a few minutes after i run that also making ifconfig a temporary solution. Is there a way to completely disable this interface? It is a ralink chipset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the specs on the "Bad one?" If so, you should be able to use `lsmod` to find the driver that is used, and prevent it from being autoloaded.

Comment: I don't, it came built into this storebought computer. I know the other is a dlink dwa-556. Ok, I will try that tommorow.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable the NIC in the BIOS so that the system will not even see it as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go into Network Manager (if that's what's running) and set the configuration for that device to not be enabled on boot.